# Anyone has an idea how this website www.nikebetterworld.com was done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web

I'm a newbie on web development and I would like to create a page that is similar to how nikebetterworld was done. I want to know where should I start studying to achieve a design like this. My initial thoughts of it was like there are 3 or 4 layers that have different scrolling speed for it to have a 3d like effect. How could I achieve that on web? Where should I start? Thank you in advance.

Comment: where should you start?  View --> Source

Comment: first learn css, html & javascript basis http://htmldog.com/

Comment: Welcome to [SO] please read the [faq].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These should help get you started:

- [One Page Website, Vertical Parallax](http://www.webdesignshock.com/one-page-website/)
- [jQuery Scroll Parallax Plugin](http://www.davecranwell.com/content/jquery-scroll-parallax-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

Yup, it was done using jQuery. The technique that's being used is called parallax scrolling. Here's another site that uses it: http://www.rowtothepole.com/.

Basically some items move more than others while scrolling.